# Objective-C typealias taking precedence over Swift class

Tags: objective-c, swift, namespaces

Using Swift 3 with XCode 8.1 (8B62)

I have a class called `Category` which I reference in another class like this: `Foo(Category.self)`. However, the Swift compiler gives the following error: `Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred`. Inspecting the class shows that Swift thinks I'm referring to `typealias Category - OpaquePointer` which is some built in typealias. More information about the typealias here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/category.

As far as I understand the compiler should favor symbols in the current module. How do I indicate to the compiler that I want the class in my module? This code apparently broke in the latest update to XCode 8B62.

Comment: @Rob thanks for the suggestion, but that also did not work. I figured out that the problem was caused by a bad merge conflict resolution. There were missing references in the `project.pbxproj` file which caused the compiler to ignore the file when building. Fixed by removing and and adding the file back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the project.pbxproj. A previous merge conflict was missing some references which broke the compiler from recognizing the symbols in the file. I had to remove the reference to the file and add it as a new file again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to beat this typealias with another one of your own:

```
typealias MyCategory = Category
```

You can now use `MyCategory` instead of Category wherever the compiler misunderstands your intent.  Of course, you can still use `Category` as long as the compiler knows what you want.  As an aside, I'd suggest avoiding type names in my code that are too similar to Objective-C/Swift keywords.

Alternatively, you can qualify the type name with the name of the target.  For example, if your your target (or module) is called `abc`, then use `abc.Category`.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this doesn't solve the issue unless I rename my `Category` class to `MyCategory`. This isn't something that I want to do since I want this to match the naming scheme on the backend. Is there no way to specify the class that I want to reference through syntax?